# Deployed Node.js application to bluemix, error : cannot find concept-insights-devoxx.mybluemix.net/css/style.css

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, concept-insights

The style.css lives in public/css folder and config/express.js has 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));

Still I am getting the following error [image]

Please help , Thanks, Sandhya

Comment: The github repository is https://github.com/sandhya9/Insights

Comment: That github repo link does not work. Is it private maybe? Typo?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your missing css is the problem. It would just mess up your styling on the page.
The TypeError above that seems more to the point. An object property "offsetTop" was referred to, but the object doesn't actually exist (or something that was supposed to create it, didn't return anything).

I'd guess that might have been what caused the 502 error, or perhaps the other way around (i.e. a proper response could not be received from the api call, and for some reason that case was not considered by whoever wrote the logic that comes after that).
Do you have the relevant code that you could post perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer! The problem was in manifest.yml, where I was binding to a different instance of Concept Insights service. Therefore, the credentials given in app.js for the instance of Concept Insights populated with my corpus were getting overwritten.

Thanks for looking at this issue !

Sandhya